# Adding a Vector2 blurs the image

Tags: c#, xna, resolution, xna-4.0

I have this code (XNA 4):

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
foreach (Tile tile in TileList)
{
    if (col > NumTiles.X) {
        row++;
    }
    tile.Position = new Vector2(TileDimensions.X / 2, TileDimensions.Y / 2) + new Vector2(col * TileDimensions.X, row * TileDimensions.Y) + Margins + Position;
    col++;
}
```

My problem is that it draws the tiles blurry.

If I use this code instead (I delete the first Vector2 from the position):

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
foreach (Tile tile in TileList)
{
    if (col > NumTiles.X) {
        row++;
    }
    tile.Position = new Vector2(col * TileDimensions.X, row * TileDimensions.Y) + Margins + Position;
    col++;
}
```

It draws them fine.

Images:

[image: LowRes]

[image: HighRes]

EDIT: I just found that I need to cast the numbers as integers, or the spritebatch does some funky inbetween pixel stuff which happens to blur my image

Comment: Your explanation and images don't make sense. The images look the same size. Also, the images show what I would expect: the first set is offset more than the second set. Where is the code that draws the images? Or do you mean that the *offsets* are wrong somehow?

Comment: If you look carefully you can see that the top image is slightly blurred and the bottom one is sharper

Comment: Perhaps you can show us your drawing code?

Comment: I added the answer in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that I need to cast the numbers as integers, or the spritebatch does some funky inbetween pixel stuff which happens to blur my image